# CSS: Display only the first two letters of a string

Tags: css

Is it possible to display only the first two letters of a string using pure CSS?

So far I have tried (without success):

- :first-letter (targets only the first letter and does not work for me anyway)
- :nth-of-everything (requires additional javascript)
- text-overflow: ellipsis; (is adding points)
- overflow: hidden; (only works if the text-size does not change, clumsy solution)

Is there another way?

Comment: You have to add spans per character to get per character control in CSS

Comment: @David: CSS is designed for display purposes. Therefore there should be a way to hide hide letters (without changing the document)? Furthermore CSS 3 added a lot of features to change documents e.g. with :after / :before

Comment: @Joseph: Can not control the HTML output here. This is why I am searching for a solution.

Comment: It's designed for display *styling* purposes.

Comment: @Blackbam Can you add JavaScript?

Comment: @Joseph yes but this applies as soon as the document is ready - I would prefer a CSS only solution if there is any way.

Comment: @Blackbam I don't think there is a way to do it with any standard current CSS. The next best thing is something like http://letteringjs.com/

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to do this in pure css! 
It uses the `ch` font-dependent unit.

```css
.two_chars{
  font-family: monospace;
  width: 2ch;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.large{
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="two_chars">
  Some long text.
</div>
<div class="two_chars large">
  Even longer text.
</div>
```

Unfortunately this works only with ***monospace fonts*** and not in older browsers.

Comment: Nice solution I will accept if there is no solution for non-monospace fonts.

Comment: It didn't quite work for me - probably because of an accumulation of other CSS getting in the way

Comment: Seems to require display:block;

Answer (score 5):

Although I agree css is primarily for styling; there are use cases for "displaying" content using:

```
text-overflow: ellipsis

<div class="myClass">
  My String
</div>

.myClass {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 39px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Will show truncated "My"

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/22segmcn/1/)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go with monospaced fonts, but just want to display as many characters as you want in the available/specified width (without showing half chars), you can use the a work-break rule while making sure you're not displaying the second line:

```
.initials {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 300;
  overflow: hidden;
  word-break: break-all;
  height: 80px;
  line-height: 80px
}
```

Example here: https://codepen.io/stevendegroote/pen/GRgjQoG

Hope this helps anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, you can do it using nth-of-everything but it requires additional javascript.

For a single letter you can do this :

```
#txt {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#txt::first-letter {
  visibility: visible;
}

<p id='txt'>hello</p>
```

here is the fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/nvf890vo/

For multiple letters you have to mix with html, for example :

```
<p><span class='show'>He</span>llo</p>
```

And apply the visible state to class "show".