# Apply first 2 characters of string another styling

Tags: css

Is it possible to style the first 2 characters of a message another styling?

```
::first-letter
```

Does not do the trick, also looked [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35328019/css-display-only-the-first-two-letters-of-a-string), but this only hides the other ones.

Is it perhaps possible with the new pseudo elements? Or use the `ch` in combination with `::first-letter`?

This is what I want to achieve but I have no clue how to do it with pure CSS. [image]

**NOTE**, I ***can not*** change the HTML.

```
<h4 class="date">10 Mar. 2022</h4>
```

Comment: A first 2 character selector wouldn't help since `1 Mar. 2022` will break that. Don;t think this can be down with just CSS. Some JS would do the trick ofc.

Comment: You can put the first two letters into a span and style it. example <h4 class="date"><span style="color: red;">10</span> Mar. 2022</h4>

Comment: @wissemmaalel OP can't change the HTML

Comment: Can you use javascript

Comment: Not possible with CSS

Comment: <p id="demo"></p>

<script>
 document.getElementById(demo).innerHTML= "<span>He</span>llo";
</script>

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with pure CSS since there is [no way of (dynamically) selecting the first 'word'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55612/css-to-select-style-first-word).

---

Consider a [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) alternative that wraps the first part in an `<em></em>` that can be styled with some CSS.

```js
const e = document.querySelector('.date');
const t = e.innerHTML.split(' ');

e.innerHTML = `<em class='up'>${t.shift()}</em> ${t.join(' ')}`
```

```css
.up {
  color: darkblue;
  font-size: x-large;
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  font-style: unset;
}

h4 {
  color: lightblue;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h4 class="date">10 Mar. 2022</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mixture of JS and css to achieve what you are looking for.
First, just split the different parts (day/month/year) into different spans and add styling accordingly. An example as follows.

```js
var text = $('.date').text();
var textArr = text.split(/\s+/);

$('.date').html(`<span class="day">${textArr[0]}</span>&nbsp;
                <span class="month">${textArr[1]}</span>&nbsp;
                <span class="year">${textArr[2]}</span>`);
```

```css
.month {
  color: red;
}

.day {
  color: blue;
}

.year {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 class="date">10 Mar. 2022</h4>
```